# Can I add a RegionPlot to a 2d slider?

Tags: manipulate, overlay

I would like to demonstrate a bifurcation plot in parameter space for the Selkov equations. I am using a 2d slider to select the value of the parameters $a$ and $b$ that determine the stability of the equilibrium in the system. Here is my *working* code to do so; my question is after the code:

```
Manipulate[
 a = ab[[1]];
 b = ab[[2]];
 x0 = 1;
 y0 = 1;
 tmax = 100;
 sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t] + a*y[t] + x[t]^2*y[t], 
    y'[t] == b - a*y[t] - x[t]^2*y[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x, 
    y}, {t, 0, tmax}];
 Show[
  Plot[{b/(a + x^2), x/(a + x^2)}, {x, 0, 3}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 6}}],
  ParametricPlot[{x[t] /. Flatten[sol], y[t] /. Flatten[sol]}, {t, 0, 
    tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.001]}]
  ],
 {{ab, {0.08, 0.6}}, {0, 0}, {0.2, 1.2}}]
```

I would like to overlay a RegionPlot on top of the 2D Slider to serve as a guide for where to click within the slider. I already tried doing this using a Locator, which works fine for manipulating the value, but then I had an awful mess trying to use a GraphicsRow to show both the locator plot and the solution plot, when the locator axes were no longer confined within the region plot. It would be much cleaner to simply overlay the region right onto the slider, as pictured in the following:

[image: Region Plot overlaid on 2D Slider]

Is this possible while keeping the code relatively simple - i.e. I don't want to build a whole UI front end for this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how you used `LocatorPane`, but I'd do it like this:

```
With[{bg = (* background *)
   RegionPlot[x + 0.1 Abs[y - 0.55] < 0.1, {x, 0, 0.2}, {y, 0, 1.1}, 
    FrameTicks -> None, ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
    ImageSize -> 80]},
 Manipulate[a = ab[[1]];
  b = ab[[2]];
  x0 = 1;
  y0 = 1;
  tmax = 100;
  sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t] + a*y[t] + x[t]^2*y[t], 
     y'[t] == b - a*y[t] - x[t]^2*y[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x, 
     y}, {t, 0, tmax}];
  Show[Plot[{b/(a + x^2), x/(a + x^2)}, {x, 0, 3}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 6}}], 
   ParametricPlot[{x[t] /. Flatten[sol], y[t] /. Flatten[sol]}, {t, 0,
      tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.001]}]],
  (**************************)
  {{ab, {0.08, 0.6}, "point"}, 
   Dynamic[LocatorPane[Dynamic[ab], bg]] &}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For some reason, the rendering nixed one of the frame lines.

Comment: Lovely, this is close enough to the original that I can learn quite a bit from it! Thanks!